# Why don't operator= for Json::Value?

Tags: c++, jsoncpp

example:

```
std::string strJson = R"({"foo": "bar"})";
Json::Value root = strJson; // if it implement operator=(std::string&)
```

instead

```
std::string strJson = R"({"foo": "bar"})";

Json::CharReaderBuilder builder;
Json::CharReader* reader = builder.newCharReader();

Json::Value json;
std::string errors;

bool parsingSuccessful = reader->parse(
    strJson.c_str(),
    strJson.c_str() + strJson.size(),
    &json,
    &errors
);
delete reader;
```

My think is the former is very convenient than the latter.

Why don't operator= for Json::Value?

Comment: Probably you should ask the library author(s) instead.

Comment: *"Why don't operator= for Json::Value"* `Json::Value root = strJson;` don't use `operator =`, but copy constructor. (and Json::value has constructor taking `string` but it is unrelated to parsing).

Comment: @Jarod42 Although it's called "copy initialization" it actually doesn't use the copy constructor; this syntax will invoke a non-explicit constructor of `Json::Value` that can take `strJson` as argument

Comment: This question is not very clear, if you are trying to comment on someone else's code then you should also link to the source so that others can view the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use `std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, Value&)`:

```
Json::Value root;
std::stringstream(R"({"foo": "bar"})") >> root;
```

Constructor taking `std::string` is to build a value containing the string value (and so `isString()` would return `true`).